# Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, xampp

I'm beginner with Zend technology and I have a problem when I run the project I get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): 
failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\index.php on line 55

Fatal error: require_once(): 
Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path=';C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\../../httpdocs/ZendFramework/library;C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\../application/classes;C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\../application/library/dompdf;C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\../application/library/cmcic;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\index.php on line 55
```

Comment: Is it a ZF1 or ZF2 project? If ZF1, can we see your config.ini or your bootstrap? If ZF2, are you using composer?

Comment: Is the 'Zend' folder at the same level as the index.php file ?

Comment: i put zend folder under  C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\application\library\Zend

Answer (score 2):

Using ZF1 standard structure, we usually copy Zend Framework in the library folder and then enable the Autoloader.

I will only put examples from the standard structure below, and then let's discuss them and adapt to your specifics.

Here is the application/configs/application.ini from one of my old projects:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
```

The focus here is the following line:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

You also need to check your public/index.php:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Here the set_include_path is what you want to verify. If this is well configured, you should not have any error.

From your error message, there is a configuration problem here.

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path=';**C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public../../httpdocs/ZendFramework/library**;C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public../application/classes;C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public../application/library/dompdf;C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public../application/library/cmcic;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\public\index.php** on line 55

See the bold text above: the first should be C:\xampp\htdocs\jcma\ZendFramework\library I guess, and the library should be located in this folder.

Can you copy paste a tree of your folders under C:\xampp\htdocs\ or at least describe the major directories, and paste your index.php?

Comment: i want to show you my index.php but i don't know why i can't paste it ,,(problem of reputation)

Comment: you can paste it on gist.github.com and paste the link here, that should work.

Comment: this my index.php  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f66f251f6722791a9955 and my Bootstrap.php https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fc0958ca9d60e7d00181

Comment: From line 47 to 52 in you index.php ou have a missing initial / in the path (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f66f251f6722791a9955#file-index-php-L47): DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '../../httpdocs/ZendFramework/library' => DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/../../httpdocs/ZendFramework/library'.

Comment: @ Thomas thank you ...the path of the library is wrong and i change it  ... it works ...  PATH_SEPARATOR . $rootPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '../application/library'

Answer (score 1):

It works for me very well. Look at inside:

> application/configs/application.ini

```
[production]
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

Point the path after APPLICATION_PATH to Zend Framework unpackaged folder. And the other option copy the /library/ which includes Zend folder inside to the same level of the project folder.